# Bootstrap/ChartJS - how to make value affect graph?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, chart.js

I'm looking to set up an interactive graph (fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/martinnguyen/caygv06L/10/). I've combined Bootstrap and ChartJS to give me a view of a graph, however not too sure what to do so that the buttons can provide an updated graph.

I'm a beginner and am looking for a way to do this smoothly.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
<body>

<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="col-auto">
    <label for="quoteStart" class="mr-sm-2">Quote Start</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quoteStart" placeholder="0%">
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Submit</button>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <label for="quoteCompletionRate" class="mr-sm-2">Quote Completion Rate</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quoteCompletionRate" placeholder="48.4%">
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Submit</button>
<script>
  var url = new URL(window.location.href)
  var quoteStartVal = url.searchParams.get(id="quoteStart") || quoteStartVal

  console.log({ quoteStartVal })

  document.getElementById('quoteStart').value = quoteStartVal
</script>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>


<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-zDnhMsjVZfS3hiP7oCBRmfjkQC4fzxVxFhBx8Hkz2aZX8gEvA/jsP3eXRCvzTofP" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
            datasets: [{
              label: "Overall Retained FY19 Actuals",
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(126, 42, 126, 0.2)',
              borderColor: 'rgb(126, 42, 126)',
              fill: false,
              borderWidth: 1,
              hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(184, 3, 166, 0.9)',
              hoverBorderWidth: 3,
              hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(205, 55, 190, 0.6)',
              data: [1635063, 2959406, 4839690, 6448717, 7692471, 9372588, 11066524],
            }, {
              label: "SPLY",
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.9)',
              borderColor: 'rgba(93, 191, 63, 0.9)',
              fill: false,
              pointHoverRadius: 5,
              pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'green',
              pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
              data: [962615, 1969827, 2918907, 4028890, 4931737, 5990783, 7182515, 8546794, 9791499, 11184470, 12537000, 13987457, 13987457],
              borderDash: [10, 5],
              type: 'line'
            }, {
              label: "FY19 Budget",
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)',
              borderColor: 'rgba(191, 63, 63, 0.9)',
              fill: false,
              pointHoverRadius: 5,
              pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'red',
              pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
              data: [1596798, 3065773, 4593808, 6206344, 7562983, 9075517, 10632793, 12242169, 13764737, 15152489, 16615769, 18178526],
              borderDash: [10, 5],
              type: 'line'
            }, {
              label: "Predicted Model",
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.9)',
              borderColor: 'purple',
              fill: false,
              pointHoverRadius: 5,
              pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'green',
              pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
              data: [ , , , , , , , 8546794*quoteStartVal, 9791499, 11184470, 12537000, 13987457, 13987457],
              borderDash: [10, 5],
                  type: 'line'
            }],

        },

        // Configuration options go here
        options: {
          scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                scaleLabel: {
                  display: true,
                  labelString: 'GWP $',
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                  fontStyle: 'bold',
                },
                  ticks: {
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                      beginAtZero: true
                  }
              }],
              xAxes: [{
                scaleLabel: {
                  display: true,
                  labelString: 'Month',
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                  fontStyle: 'bold',
                  segmentShowStroke: false,
                  animateScale: true,
                },
                  ticks: {
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                  }
              }]
          },
          responsive: true,
          legend:{
            position: 'top',
            fullWidth: true,
            labels: {
              fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
              fontStyle: 'italic',
              fontSize: 12,
            }
          },
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: ['Overall GWP - a view'],
            fontSize: [30],
            fontFamily: "Arial",
            fontStyle: 'bold',
          },
          tooltips: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'nearest',
            callbacks: {
              label: function(tooltipItems,data){
                return 'Overall GWP:' + ' $' + tooltipItems.yLabel;
              }
            }
          }
        }
    });

</script>
```

In the JSFiddle above, I would like to find a way so that if I typed in any of the fields above, I could create an extra line in a graph that would represent the future model (e.g. Quote Start increased by 10%, therefore a new blue line would pop up and reflect what the 10% increase).